# PHP for-each loop not working?

Tags: javascript, php, loops, foreach, maps

My for-each not working. Not looping javascript code. Could someone please provide some code to help?

```js
  $guy= queryMysql("SELECT lat, long FROM members WHERE user='$guy'");
  while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($guy)){

   $latitude1= $data2['lat'];
   $longitude1= $data2['long'];
   
   echo "<script>function createMarker() {
   $.goMap.createMarker(
   { 
    latitude: $latitude1, 
    longitude: $longitude1, 
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: 'Current users location', 
    html: { 
     content: '<p>This is your location $friend</p>', 
     popup: false 
    } 
   }
   );

   }</script>";
```

Comment: Did you change your variables from your earlier question?  You have `$data2['lat']` and `$data2['long']` but `homelocation` and `currentlocation` are still in your SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to build an array in your PHP loop, and provide that data to your javascript.  Something like this could work:

PHP

```
<?php
$strOut = '';
if (sizeof($following)) {
    foreach ($following as $friend) {

        $friendsloc = queryMysql("SELECT homelocation, currentlocation FROM members WHERE user='$friend'");
        while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($friendsloc)) {

            $latitude1  = $data2['homelocation'];
            $longitude1 = $data2['currentlocation'];

            $strOut .= '{"lat": '.$latitude1.', "lon": '.$longitude1.'},';


        }
    }



}
$strOut = 'var locations = [' . rtrim($strOut,",") . ']';
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // get a Google map centred roughly on the John Dalton Building: 
    $('#map').goMap({
        latitude: 53.472342399999995,
        longitude: -2.2398096,
        zoom: 12,
        maptype: 'ROADMAP',
        scaleControl: true
    });



    <?php echo $strOut; ?>
    // now add a marker: 
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      $.goMap.createMarker({
          latitude: locations[i].lat,
          longitude: locations[i].lon,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          title: 'Current users location',
          html: {
              content: '<p>This is your location </p>',
              popup: false
          }
      });
    }




});
```

Comment: was missign a ; at the end of $strOut. But this still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You create numerous createMarker() functions and the last overrides all previous ones. So when you call it later, you get exactly one call with the last parameters. Do not create a function, push the coordinates to some storage and loop over it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $friendsloc = mysql_query("SELECT lat, long FROM members WHERE user='$friend'");
            while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($friendsloc)){

             $latitude1= $data2['lat'];
             $longitude1= $data2['long'];

                echo "<script>function createMarker() {
                $.goMap.createMarker(
                { 
                    latitude: $latitude1, 
                    longitude: $longitude1, 
                     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: 'Current users location', 
                    html: { 
                        content: '<p>This is your location $friend</p>', 
                        popup: false 
                    } 
                }
                );

                }</script>";
                    }
                        ?>
```